# How to create custom chatbot button in salesforce

Tags: omnichannel, einstein-chatbot, chatbot

[image: existing chatbot button]

[image: i want to create chatbot button like this]

I want to create chatbot button as shown in picture 2. Picture 1 is having existing salesforce chat button.What are the ways i can create this chatbot button in salesforce or is there is any way to customize existing chat button like this

Comment: Can you try following the click path and confirm if this is what you've been looking for: `Setup> Chat Buttons and Invitations>Chat Button Customization section> Online Image`  [Related](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.live_agent_button_settings.htm&type=5#:~:text=Sets%20the%20custom%20button%20graphic%20that%20appears%20when%20the%20chat%20button%20is%20available%20for%20customers%20to%20request%20new%20chats.)

Comment: Hi shweta i followed this approach still i can see the existing button as shown in picture 1

Comment: Are you saying that you completely want to remove the bottom right "[Chaticon]Chat with expert " and just have a clickable image with "Chat now"?

Comment: Yes you are right i want to do same

Answer (score 1):

You will need to go with the [bootstrap API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/embedded_services_web_bootstrap_chat.htm) approach to start a chat session from any button. Example [site](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service)

From the doc,

> Add a Custom Chat Button
>
> Here’s an example of how to apply this API. Hide the default
> Salesforce chat button and replace it with a button that matches your
> company’s brand.
>
> To hide the standard button, include this line in your embedded code
> snippet: embedded_svc.settings.displayHelpButton = false;.
>
> On click of your company’s branded button, invoke
> embedded_svc.bootstrapEmbeddedService(); to surface the chat
> experience for your end user.
>
> To show a basic button that invokes the bootstrapEmbeddedService()
> function:
>
> ```
> <script type='text/javascript'>
>   function bootstrapChat() {
>       embedded_svc.bootstrapEmbeddedService();
>   }
> </script>
> <button onclick="bootstrapChat()">
>   Click me to show the Embedded Chat experience.
> </button>
> ```

Comment: Could you please provide steps to add this code snippet. I have modified the code but not sure were to paste it.

Answer (score -3):

You have to use the LWC component and call that button's div class in the LWC script. But there is one lightning Locker present on the community site. You have to disable that
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_locker_service

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).